# Ionic 2 Paypal Express checkout

Tags: angular, typescript, paypal, ionic2, paypal-sandbox

Hey i had never used any pay-pal API before. I want to know how to use paypal express checkout method in ionic 2. I am not finding an npm plugin for that can anybody help me with this!

Comment: are you looking for http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/ ?

Comment: Does this plugin works with express checkout??

Comment: This plugin is working perfect thanks